# How to change/tweak Python 3.10 default SSL settings for requests - sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, python-requests, python-3.10

**The issue:**

[Python 3.10 increased the default security settings of the TLS stack](https://bugs.python.org/issue43998). Awesome. I have a legacy application running something that theses settings do not like. I don't know what exactly. How do tweak these settings to let my request through?

**The story:**

I'm writing a small script to extract some information from a Jazz RTC instance running on premise. It clearly has a... problematic ssl certificate. Nothing that a "verify=False" shouldn't fix. Well, it does not.
When I run the following code in python 3.10...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    data = {
        'j_username': username,
        'j_password': password
    }

    result = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False).json

    print(result)
```

... i get this handshake error.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=...): Max retries exceeded with url: /ccm/authenticated/j_security_check (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)'))
```

BUT, it works without a problem on Python 3.9. Looking around for an answer, I found out about the heightened security defaults added to python 3.10, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006708/getting-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-when-trying-to-connect-to-imap)... but nothing on how to tweak them to make this work with my requests.

**The details:**

[This is what the browser developer tools report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIipi.png)

- As usual, this is a very limited enterprise environment. I can't do
  much. No admin privileges.
- The department responsible for that host, as expected, says it can't be fixed, giving some shallow excuses.
- "If it works on 3.9, why not use it?" - Well, several reasons. The major one being 3.10 is the version accepted for use in the company environment. If they even find out I sneaked in a conda 3.9 venv to test stuff, I'll get a mean lecture.

Any help is appreciated! o/

Comment: Look around a `ssl_cipher` option in the toolkits you use, with a value of `@SECLEVEL=1` to reduce the level for your specific connection (better to do that than to list ciphers).

Comment: Thanks a BUNCH, @PatrickMevzek ! Your tip led me in the right path, found a config that solved it for me. I'll add an answer to this question with the specific solution in a bit. o/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PatrickMevzek 's comment led me to other queries and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small).

Which showed me how to change the used ciphers AND security level. The following snippet from @bgoeman worked for my environment:

```
import urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```

Obviously, in general THIS SHOULD NOT BE USED. This will allow for man-in-the-middle attacks and other nasty things. Be careful and mindful when changing these settings.