# requests.exceptions.SSLError Max retries exceeded with url sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1, sslv3

I was running a script where this was functioning correctly. I reinstalled Python, and now I'm getting a `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool`. I'm aware I can add `verify=False` and it should get rid of the error, but what exactly is causing this failure, and how can I get around it without adding the flag `verify=False` anything helps!

Here's a snippet of the exception - it may be a bit much but I'm not entirely sure of the issue

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002)
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you're connecting to a service that only offers obsolete SSL ciphers, and Python is now refusing to connect? That was the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006708/getting-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-when-trying-to-connect-to-imap). Unfortunately, that error corresponds with many possible causes, and we can't debug this any further, because we don't have access to the server you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.