# python ssl cert issues (SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE)

Tags: python, ssl

I have a script that works fine with python3.7, but get the SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with python 3.10. I have tried setting the SSL_CERT_FILE and SSL_CERT_DIR environment variables. But it doesn't seem to be helping. Any suggestions?

The script works with this python

```
$ python3.7 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', capath='/etc/pki/tls/certs',openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem',openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/etc/pki/tls/certs')
```

But fails with this python

```
$ python3.10 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem',openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs')
```

How do I configure python3.10 to have the same values as python3.7. If I add the following lines to the script

```
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem'
os.environ["SSL_CERT_FILE"] = '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem'
os.environ["SSL_CERT_DIR"] = '/etc/pki/tls/certs'
```

I get this and still get the "[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)" error. Here are the ssl.get_default_verify_paths results.

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', capath='/etc/pki/tls/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs')
```

Comment: Is this answer related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71007463/3969110

Comment: Maybe you need a newer version of OpenSSL
Python 3.10 requires at least OpenSSL 1.1.1, source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10939