why does the request work if I'm using Invoke-RestMethod but it doesn't if I'm using requests from python?
The Invoke-RestMethod looks like:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'url' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers

The header contains a bearer token
The python code looks like:
import requests

url = "some_url"

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)


It results in an error:
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<some_host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: "<url>" (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1133)')))

The reuqest works if I'm using postman or Invoke-RestMethod, but it doesn't work if I'm using python's request module.
The code for python and invoke method were generated using postman.
What could be a possible explanation for this?

It's easier to diagnose questions that have a [mcve]. Can you provide the URL so that we can reproduce the behavior ourselves? What version of Python are you using? What version of OpenSSL (that's ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION). Are you running both tests from the same host? This question includes some useful diagnostics you should consider, as well as a potential solution (but it's not clear you're facing the same problem).

You are connecting using SSL v3, which is pretty old.  See this question for more details about how the base security has been updated as of Python 3.10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006708/getting-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-when-trying-to-connect-to-imap

First, update your SSL + requests package as @James pointed out, SSL 3.0 is super old and has known security issues. Then, you may want to use requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs) rather than the generic requests.request(), here shown in grey for dramatic effect. Finally, some servers outright reject SSL 3.0 in favour of TLS >= 1.2. TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are bout' to be deprecated
